# Objective-C: which getter method should I implement for read-only BOOL properties?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I am writing a subclass for the UITextRange class, which has the following property:

```
 @property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isEmpty) BOOL empty
```

Should I write an implementation for the `empty` or the `isEmpty` method in my subclasss? Should I write implementations for both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getter=isEmpty` means that the getter method named `- (BOOL)isEmpty` is called when you write `someVariable = obj.empty`. So you should implement the `isEmpty` method.